# SQL Union Join Issue

Tags: sql, join, union

Need help with SQL `UNION`.

I have 2 tables listed below. `ListPriorities` contains a list of names for each priority. Each `Tasker` has one priority associated with it.

Table 1: ListPriorities

Columns:

```
ListPrioritiesID, ListPrioritiesName, isActive
```

Table 2: Tasker

Columns:

```
TaskerID, TaskOrderNumber, ListPrioritiesID
```

In the admin area an admin can add a priority or remove a priority which changes the `isActive` column from 1 to 0. There is sometimes a `Tasker` that has a `Priority` that has been removed. I need to get the list of active priorities and an inactive priority if it is associated with the `Tasker` in question.

This is what in query thus far:

```
SELECT ListPrioritiesID, ListPrioritiesName 
FROM ListPriorities
WHERE isActive = 1 

UNION 

SELECT TaskerID, TaskOrderNumber, T.ListPrioritiesID, LP.ListPrioritiesID 
FROM Tasker T
INNER JOIN ListPriorities LP ON T.ListPrioritiesID = LP.ListPrioritiesID
WHERE TaskOrderNumber = 'ABC123'
```

Comment: Your unions have different number of columns, so it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do union between two relations only if they have the same schema.In your case the schemas are not same.

```
SELECT LP.ListPrioritiesID, LP.ListPrioritiesName 
FROM ListPriorities LP 
WHERE LP.isActive = 1 
   OR LP.ListPrioritiesID IN (SELECT t.ListPrioritiesID 
                              FROM Tasker t 
                              WHERE t.TaskOrderNumber = 'ABC123')
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I was working off another example that had used UNION, but this was far easier.